# Recover Encrypted Data from windows.old (WIN10)

Tags: windows, encryption, certificate, efs

I recently had to reinstall windows 10 because it became unusable.  I've got all my data back from windows.old and other sources but...  Without me realizing it, windows had encrypted some of the data in AppData.  Specifically, AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/saves...  Needless to say, it's of high importance!

I've been trying import the cert file from windows.old/users/{username}/roaming/microsoft/~my/certificates/ via certmgr.msc.  This works and the file shows up in the Personal->Certificates.  However, it does not import the Private Key.  The private key should be the password of my user account on the previous installation.  That's the default, and since I wasn't aware of the encryption, I wouldn't have set a different private key password.

My current user account is now tied to an online Microsoft/OneDrive, so it's a little different...

So how can I decrypt these files with the cert and a password of the private key?  I feel like I'm 75% of the way there, but can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Without the private key you will be unable to decrypt the data.  Having just the public key in this case isn't enough

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to extract the private key from windows.old?  Or recreate the private key since I know the original password?

Comment: I ended up finding a 2 week old copy of the files on my OneDrive account, so that will have to do.  Still not sure how those files ended up encrypted to begin with, but nothing to do about it now...